# OnTap API: How can I get volume attributes?

Tags: java, netapp

I am using OnTap API and I am talking to 7-Mode NetApp filer. I am able to get a list of volumes, but I cannot figure out how to get volume attributes. I tried to use  VolumeGetIterResponse class, here is a code snippet:

```
VolumeGetIterRequest volumeGetIter = new VolumeGetIterRequest();
volumeGetIter.setMaxRecords(100);
List<VolumeAttributes> volAttributes = volumeGetIterResponse.getAttributesList();

for (VolumeAttributes vas : volAttributes) {
    VolumeExportAttributes vs = vas.getVolumeExportAttributes();
}
```

When running this code, I get an error:

> Unable to find API: volume-get-iter

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your error, it appears you're using the "volume-get-iter" API. This is a Cluster-Mode API. Since you're talking to a 7-mode, you will need "volume-list-info".